# Make a NSAlert the topmost window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsalert

I've created the main window in my application to have these settings:

```
[self setLevel:kCGDesktopWindowLevel + 1];
[self setCollectionBehavior:
     (NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | 
      NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary | 
      NSWindowCollectionBehaviorIgnoresCycle)];
```

It's a very custom window that sort of floats above the desktop.

In addition, it's a menu-bar application (`LSUIElement`).

Alright, so I need to display an alert if something isn't right.  Here's how I'm doing it:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"" 
                                 defaultButton:@"" 
                               alternateButton:@"" 
                                   otherButton:@"" 
                     informativeTextWithFormat:@""];
[alert runModal];
```

Of course I have filled in the buttons and other text.

Here's my problem: When my application is not currently the key application, and this alert pops up, it's not a key window.  Like this:

[image]

See how the window isn't selected? Is there any way around this without changing my whole app window level?  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried activating your application in the code that displays the alert?

```
[[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:0];
```

If passing 0 doesn't work, you can pass `NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps` as your option, but Apple recommends against it unless really necessary (see docs for NSRunningApplication).

---

**Update:** You have activate before running the alert. This works for me in a new app with LSUIElement set:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText: @"Blah"
                                     defaultButton: @"Blah"
                                   alternateButton: @"Blah"
                                       otherButton: @"Blah"
                         informativeTextWithFormat: @"Blah"];

    [[NSRunningApplication currentApplication] activateWithOptions:NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doing so still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Did you add it before or after the runModal call? runModal blocks so you have to put the NSRunningApplication call first. See updated answer.

Comment: `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` is shorter

Comment: If this still isn't working for you, make sure it's the line _right before_ `[alert runModal]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support 10.5 also. you can use

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Forcing an application to move forefront is a rather bad idea.
One would probably prefer to make the alert floating over everything using the dedicated NSPanel property 'floatingPanel':

```
NSPanel* panel = static_cast<NSPanel*>([alert window]);
panel.floatingPanel = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure the NSAlert is topmost use:

```
alert.window.level = NSFloatingWindowLevel;
```

Otherwise, if you want the default button to be highlighted, use (as others have suggested):

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps : YES];
```